# Calculating the maximum of a function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, optimization, calculus-of-variations

> How can one determine $$\max_{f_0,f_1}\frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_1(y)^xf_0(y)^{1-x}\log\left(\frac{f_1(y)}{f_0(y)}\right)\mbox{d}y}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_1(y)^xf_0(y)^{1-x}\mbox{d}y}$$
>
> given
>
> $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_1(y)^xf_0(y)^{1-x}\mbox{d}y=a$$
>   where $x$ is a given number in $(0,1)$ and $f_0$ and $f_1$ are some positive density functions on $\mathbb{R}$?
>
> Note that $0<a<1$ holds due to the integral of a positive function and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.
>
> It would be also nice to know the minimum as well based on the same condition. Please let me know if you have any idea related to any possible solution of this problem.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Did you have reason to believe this is a convex optimization problem? I see no reason why it should be.

Comment: yes nice chicken))

Comment: If it is concave then the first-order condition will be useful in finding the maximum. If it is a convex function then we know the maximum is obtained at the boundary of the feasible set.

Comment: @ErikMiehling i would rather guess that it is supposed to be either concave or convex but I dont know how to show it. KL divergence is convex and the nominator is very similar to KL divergence where there is $f_1^xf_0^{1-x}$ instead of $f_1$. Apart from a normalization factor $f_1^xf_0^{1-x}$ is also a density function.

Comment: The word _density function_ implies that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_1(y)\mbox{d}y=1=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_0(y)\mbox{d}y$?

Comment: @Qmechanic sure.

Comment: This is an interesting problem, any progress on this?

Comment: @ErikMiehling According to my derivations i have $D(f_1,f_0)<\frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_1(y)^xf_0(y)^{1-x}\log\left(\frac{f_1(y)}{f_0(y)}\right)\mbox{d}y}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_1(y)^xf_0(y)^{1-x}\mbox{d}y}<D(f_0,f_1)$ with $D(\cdot)$ being KL divergence. If $f_0(y)=f_1(-y)$ then it is zero.